# Blender won't let me change the segments in a sphere

Tags: mesh, objects

I'm trying to add a sphere and decrease the rings/segments but for some reason the box to do that is greyed out when I add it.

This happens to all the other objects I try to add... I'm thinking it's in some setting/preference but I just don't know

[image: UV Sphere mesh with custom box]

[image: custom box]

Comment: did you left click in the box?  Does it remain grey?  Sounds like a bug, so which version of blender?

Comment: when i try to left click on the box, it just deselects the object which makes the box go away. I'm using the 3.0.1 blender for the m1 chip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Preferences > System*, make sure that *Global Undo* is activated. It probably has to do with the fact that editing the primitive mesh requires to do an undo.

[image]

EDIT: Moved explanation here from comments per request

The panel in question is actually the [*Adjust Last Operation*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation) panel, sometimes known as the "Redo" panel. When you see it, the operator has already been executed and so its state change is on the undo stack. When you change a value in the panel, under the covers, Blender performs an undo and then calls the operator again with the new parameters. If Global Undo isn't available, then Blender can't do its behind-the-scenes undo.

Comment: I never understood what does `Global undo` do

Comment: It has to do with the last action but I don't know more  ;)

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Previously in Blender versions edit mode undo stack and object mode undo stacks were separated. That meant undoing in object mode after spending hours tweaking your mesh in edit mode could potentially irreversibly undo all your changes. I think that's what global undo is doing, it's putting all operations in the same undo stack

Comment: OK. But, I don't understand how it is related to greyed out things.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka The panel in question is actually the "Last operator _redo_" panel.  When you see it, the operator has already been executed and so its state change is on the undo stack.  When you change a value in the panel, under the covers, Blender performs an undo and then calls the operator again with the new parameters.  If Global Undo isn't available, then Blender can't do its behind-the-scenes undo.

Comment: @MartyFouts thank you. This explanation should be added to the answer. It's good to see an answer that solves the problem but it's better if we can understand why.

Comment: Thank you so much @MartyFouts you really saved me from using extra vertices i didn't need

Comment: @ari It was moonboots that saved you the vertices; I just explained why it works.

Comment: thank you both nonetheless :)